# how can I return 400 error code in haproxy using acl

Tags: haproxy

I'm using Haproxy 1.8 and have a whole bunch of endpoints I'd like to retire. The configuration contains a lot more frontend and backends which are they to stay, but for those I want to retire I'd like to return a 400 error code to the clients.

I was thinking to make use of ACLs in this form:

```
acl host_website1.domain.tld hdr_dom(host) -m beg website1
acl host_website2.domain.tld hdr_dom(host) -m beg website2
acl host_website3.domain.tld hdr_dom(host) -m beg website3
```

Now, those would be the conditions, but I'm not sure how to instruct HAP to return http 400 error code.

Answer (score 0):

```
http-request deny deny_status 400 if host_website1.domain.tld
```